# ERROR: Remote Operations Not Permitted on Object Tables or User-Defined Type Columns

Tags: oracle

Whenever I am trying to fetch data  from remote table using db link and put inside the collection variable, I am getting ORA-22804 Error.
I don't have access to the remote database.

I tried recreating the type using oid, but still facing the same issue.

```
create or replace type type_demo as table of varchar2(32767);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_TEST(EMP_ID IN TYPE_DEMO,E_NAME OUT TYPE_DEMO)
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT EMP_NAME BULK COLLECT INTO E_NAME FROM EMP_TABLE@CDM_LINK WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID MEMBER OF EMP_ID;
END;
```

/

Whenever I am trying to test the above procedure I am getting ORA-22804 Error:

```
DECLARE
A TYPE_DEMO:=TYPE_DEMO('1001');
B TYPE_DEMO:=TYPE_DEMO();
BEGIN
PROC_TEST(A,B);
FOR I IN 1..B.COUNT LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(B(i));
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all:

```
ORA-22804 remote operations not permitted on object tables or user-defined type columns
```

You're trying to do exactly that - remote operation on a user defined type `type_demo`, over a database link `CDM_LINK`.

Cheers